# Exposing a method or property to be accessed from outside of Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In [Vue's guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering) they show that you can change the data of your Vue instance created by `new Vue` directly from the console. But after going deeper into Vue and growing my application, this approach no longer works. As my `new Vue` instance no longer has that simple `el` declaration and a direct `data` property, but instead is now created with the following code:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Values that get declared in its `data` property no longer behave like from their guide. I've tried to change this part of the code into:

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        test_var: 'Hello world'
    },
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
app.$mount('#app');
```

But calling `app.test_var` from console reports `undefined`. I've also tried calling methods from my `Vue.mixin()` declarations, but they are undefined as well.

What i want is to expose a method through which i could toggle a property on my main config. My use-case would be when users report that something doesn't work properly, i want to be able to say "Go to the console, and just type in this thing to turn debug on, and then tell me what the console says". So if i could do something like `app.debug = true` or something like that, you know?

## EDIT

It seems the problem is not just exposing the data on the `Vue` instance, but something deeper than that. I don't understand at which point this distinction started, but for example if i were to change the variable name from `var app = new Vue()...` to `var myApp = new Vue()...`, then invoking `myApp` in the console says `undefined`. The only reason `app` is not undefined is because it finds the HTML element with the `id="app"`.

So could it have something to do with the "non-simple" initialisation of Vue where i went from just including the Vue script and writing string templates as in that guide, to now having single-file components that are being compiled into some more advanced stuff that are no longer accessible simply through a javascript variable? The project was created with `vue-cli`, and i am serving it with `npm` via `npm run serve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe storing your `app` in `window` can solve your problem.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        test_var: 'Hello world'
    },
    methods: {
      method() {
        console.log(this.test_var)
      }
    },
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
});
app.$mount('#app');

window.app = app
```

Then in console:

```
app.method()
```

Comment: I wasn't a big fan of putting the entire app in `window`, but i did manage to solve my situation by only assigning the debug method with `window.debug = this.debug`, so this does do the trick! Although i'm still curious at what point the code from the guide stopped being applicable :P

Answer (score 0):

you can access the data object with the following syntax :

```js
app.$data.test_var
```

**Or :**

switch your data to a function that returns an object :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      test_var: 'Hello world'
    }
  },
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
app.$mount('#app');

app.test_var // 'Hello world'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But this doesn't solve it for me, i've added an "EDIT" section under my original question, if you have any further ideas, it's appreciated.